# CreateProcess always fails

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I tried to create a process with `CreateProcess` in C++. But this function always returns false.

Here is some pieces of my code:

```cpp
#if UNICODE
    std::wstring exename =
#else
    char* exename =
#endif
    _T("‪c:\\Windows\\Notepad.exe");

    STARTUPINFO si;
    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    if (!CreateProcess(exename, NULL, NULL, NULL, false, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        cout << "Error code=" << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
```

The program shows error code 123. And I tried make `exename` as the second parameter, then the error code changed to 2.

I have googled it for a day and have tried changing charset of the project into Multibyte or Unicode, replacing `CreateProcess` with `CreateProcessA` or `CreateProcessW`, replacing `char *` with `LPCSTR` or `LPCWSTR` and many other attempts. None of them solved the problem but show same error code.

I am running that code in Windows 10 and compile it with Visual Studio 2013. I am sure that "c:\Windows\Notepad.exe" exists on my computer.

It has driven me mad, please help me. Any hint shall be appreciated.

**Solution of this problem:**

Don't copy and paste the file path from properties dialog of Windows explorer, it may contain some hidden characters.

Comment: [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror): *"You should call the `GetLastError` function **immediately** when a function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful data."* You aren't, and the return value is meaningless at the point where you are calling it. It's unclear, why you are using generic text mappings at all. Just call the Unicode version and call it a day. If you *must* use generic text mappings, just do this: `auto const exename{ _T("c:\\Windows\\Notepad.exe") };`.

Comment: If `UNICODE` is defined then your code will not compile, since you can't pass a `std::wstring` as-is to `CreateProcess()`, you need to call its `c_str()` or `data()` method, which you are not doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're trying to trick us, but there is an invisible character in front of `c:\\` (right after the `"`).

Copy/paste this line from here to make it work:

```
auto const exename = _T("c:\\Windows\\Notepad.exe");
```

You can see the hidden character using a HEX editor:

[image]

You can test this by copy/pasting the line in the question to this [online hex editor](https://hexed.it/).

Comment: In my hex editor, pasting the original text as UTF-16 reveals the "hidden" character is Unicode codepoint [U+202A LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm), which in your screenshot is being converted to byte `E2` when pasted as ANSI.

Comment: @RemyLebeau do you have any idea how it would get there?

Comment: It can get there if you are copy-pasting the fully qualified path name from a file manager into the code editor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked my code with a hex editor, then find some strange invisible characters before "c:\\". As @IInspectable saied, I copied the path from the security tab of the file's property dialog. I typed path rather than paste it, and the program worked good. Thank you very much!

Comment: @IInspectable Can you tell me the reason why hidden characters are added when copying file path from Windows explorer? Is it a bug or Windows intended to do so for some purpose?

Comment: [Why is there an invisible U+202A at the start of my file name?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150506-00/?p=44924)